# IBM watson integration with instagram

Tags: instagram, integration, ibm-watson

I'm trying to develope a chatbot to Direct Instagram. Anybody knows if is possible to integrate Watson Assistant (Chatbot) with Direct Instagram?

I saw that I had a post from 3 years ago, but recently the telegram integrated the direct into the messenger.

I would like to know if anyone has any solutions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to do it via http on node red and pull this request through chatfuel